# $p$-primary torsion of an elliptic curve in the cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extension of a $p$-adic field

Tags: nt.number-theory, local-fields, iwasawa-theory

Let $K$ be a number field and $v$ be a fixed prime above $p$. Let $k=K_v$. We have the cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_p$ extension $K_\infty/K$ and if $w$ is a prime above $v$ in $K_\infty$ we write $k_\infty=K_{\infty,w}$. 
Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over $k$ and suppose it has good ordinary reduction over $k_\infty$.

Is there a nice explicit description for the $p$-primary torsion points $E(k_\infty)_{p^\infty}$?